# Google Analytics Custom Variable/Value Report (How?)

Tags: google-analytics

I was able to setup Google Analytics to send custom variables that I can track.

I'd like to generate a report with UserId / Value and Display all of the pages
that user viewed. (Similar to reports I have seen with IP address on one column,
and viewed pages on the other)

> Custom Var 1             : label:'userId' value:'17' scope:'1' (from Chrome Analytics tool)

Google Analytics reporting is pretty complex, so I'm hoping I can get some suggestions on how to create such a report.

Answer (score 1):

i'm battling through google analytics aswell it can be really useful but to get exactly what you want can take some time.  This isn't an answer as much as its a list of a few links that i have used along the way and hope they help

http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

In here if you put ga:source ga:referralPath ga:customVarName(n)

This stack overflow answer may also help

[Create google analytics profile by filtering using a custom variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736526/create-google-analytics-profile-by-filtering-using-a-custom-variable)

i'll have to look into this myself when i m using custom variables but it look like the advanced segment section may be the way to go.

And you ve probably already seen this but its quite a nice article on custom variables

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Let us know hwo you get on...

Comment: I think Google Analytics is somewhat one dimensional.. So.. I think I have to send two custom variables.. I dunno.. It seems easy to create a segment from a variable, but to also create a segment from a specific variables value doesn't seem as easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want to create an advanced segment including your custom variable.  This should narrow the data to only that which includes the variable.  You can then look at whatever reports you want within that segment.

Using regular expressions should let you better tune the scope of the segment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in the [Megalytic](http://megalytic.com) reporting tool.  There are widgets that let you create reports which segment data by custom variable.  For example, Traffic by Custom Variable, Conversions by Custom Variable.  Disclaimer:  I am a founder of Megalytic.